# Solving a math problem. Python3 guessing the three numbers

Tags: python-3.x, math, numbers

I have to solve this problem: Looking for three numbers, the rules are the following.

```
#682 one number and its position correct
#614 one number is correct but its position incorrect
#206 two numbers are correct but their position isnt
#738 nothing is correct 
#780 one number is correct but its position wrong
```

I would like to use python to solve it, but I have no idea where to start solving it. I wouldn't like to have the answer, but a clue on how to properly do it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility is to use [Z3py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm), an open source [SAT/SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) solver. All constraints are written using [logical operations](https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf), mostly `And` and `Or`. Then, the constraints will propagate until a solution is found (or the solver assures no solution exists). The solver only looks for one possible solution. To know that it is the only one, the solver could be run again with an additional clause to find a different solution.

This specific problem seems a bit elaborate to convert to such constraints. Also, the "exactly one" constraint for #614 should be written more complex.
Nevertheless, the system finds the only solution.

The code could be cleaned somewhat via functions that explicitly check compound constraints.

```py
from z3 import Solver, Int, And, Or, Xor

a, b, c = Int('a'), Int('b'), Int('c')
s = Solver()
s.add(And(a >= 0, a <= 9))
s.add(And(b >= 0, b <= 9))
s.add(And(c >= 0, c <= 9))
# 682 one digit and its position correct
s.add(Or(And(a == 6, b != 8, c != 2), And(b == 8, a != 6, c != 2), And(c == 2, b != 8, a != 6)))
# 614 one digit is correct but its position incorrect
s.add(And(a != 6, b != 1, c != 4))
s.add(Or([a == 1, a == 4, b == 6, b == 4, c == 6, c == 1]))  # should be: exactly one
# 206 two digits are correct but their position isn't
s.add(And(a != 2, b != 0, c != 6))
n206_2 = And(Or(a == 0, c == 0), Or(a == 6, b == 6), And(b != 2, c != 2))
n206_0 = And(Or(b == 2, c == 2), Or(a == 6, b == 6), And(a != 0, c != 0))
n206_6 = And(Or(b == 2, c == 2), Or(a == 0, c == 0), And(a != 6, b != 6))
s.add(Or(n206_2, n206_0, n206_6))
# 738 nothing is correct
s.add(And([a != 7, b != 7, c != 7, a != 3, b != 3, c != 3, a != 8, b != 8, c != 8]))
# 780 one digit is correct but its position wrong
s.add(And(a != 7, b != 8, c != 0))
n780_0 = And(c != 7, c != 8, a != 8, b != 7, Xor(a == 0, b == 0))
n780_8 = And(b != 0, b != 7, a != 8, c != 0, Xor(a == 8, c == 8))
n780_7 = And(a != 0, a != 8, c != 8, b != 0, Xor(b == 7, c == 7))
s.add(Or(n780_0, n780_8, n780_7))
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```